# For which values of $x$ is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=\sin{\pi x}$.
For which values of $x$ is $f$ differentiable.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin{\pi (x+h)} - \sin{\pi x}}{h}=???$$

I don't know how I can formally prove that $f$ is differentiable for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously I can take a shortcut and state that the limit equals $\pi \cos{\pi x}$ (the derivative), so the limit exists for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. But how do I get there formally?

Comment: $sin(a+b)=sin(a)cos(b)+cos(a)sin(b)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$ and
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos t -1}{t}
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos^2t -1}{t{(\cos t+1)}}
=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-\sin^2t}{t{(\cos t+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\cdot\frac{-\sin t}{\cos t+1}\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)\cdot
\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-\sin t}{\cos t+1}\right)\\
&=1\cdot 0=0.
\end{align}
Then by @thedude's comment, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin{\pi (x+h)} - \sin{\pi x}}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to 0}
\frac{\sin{\pi x}\cos{\pi h}+\cos{\pi x}\sin{\pi h}-\sin{\pi x}}{h}\\
&=\pi\sin\pi x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos\pi h-1}{\pi h}
+\pi\cos\pi x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin\pi h}{\pi h}\\
&=\pi\sin\pi x\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos t-1}{t}
+\pi\cos\pi x\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\\
&=(\pi\sin\pi x)\cdot 0+(\pi\cos\pi x)\cdot 1\\
&=\pi\cos\pi x.
\end{align}